# Is clamp meter misreading or am I using it incorrectly?

Tags: electrical, voltage, testing

I just bought an [Ideal 61-737 Clamp Meter](https://www.lowes.com/pd/IDEAL-ID-400-Amp-TRMS-Clamp-Meter/5000022329) from Lowes and watched several instructional videos on how to use it.

I'm interested in using the Non-Contact Voltage (NCV) feature which allows me to touch the tip of it to an outlet, breaker, or any lower-voltage conductor really, and use it as a simple touch-based voltage meter.

The problem is it goes off on everything. It goes off when I touch it to my wooden desk. [It goes off when I touch it to my shoes.](https://youtu.be/Dbx03oUaa70) It even goes off when I touch it to my arms. And I know I've always said I have arms of steel, but I was only joking!

As seen in the link above, I am turning it on, switching it to the NCV setting, and touch the NCV tip to things and it beeps and lights up on everything. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: My non contact voltage tester will go off briefly when it gets moved quickly, like when I touch it to something and I'm not gentle enough. Looks like you're doing the same thing there. Does it go off when you gently touch your shoe instead of banging against it?

Comment: As @PhilippNagel writes, rapidly moving the pen through an electrostatic field (e.g. to a mildly charged object) will make the field appear as an electromagnetic field to the meter. Notice it emits a short beep warning burst, not the 3Hz voltage detection beep train.

Comment: Thanks guys, that must be it. If I move it and touch it slowly, I get nothing. if one of you wants to supply an answer, I'll happily give it the green check -- cheers.

Comment: @PhilippNagel it's all yours! If you can't or don't want, I'll wait a day and write it up. It's valuable to other readers.

Comment: Try nylon, in some cases even a slow movement will generate enough voltage , my fluke 1AC-A is 90-1000v on my nylon rain jacket it turns on with barely any movement, but my FR shirts and pants it takes some aggressive motion, the voltages are mentioned in the manual pg 13 of the one I looked up.

Comment: @P2000 while I have observed this phenomenon, it seems you can elaborate better on the reason behind it, so please go ahead and write up an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your meter is non contact voltage sensing !

It is not a non contact voltage meter see page 13 of the ideal 61737 manual.
Many think that NCV means it will read the voltage, nope you need to get to meters in the 300+ range and you still need a ground plane (usually your body connected to ground)

The EF is stating over 40v was sensed again see page 13 in the pdf

I’ve found the ncv is a trigger to hook folks especially on these cheap meters but even as a pro with a nice model almost 3x the price most are just “tick testers” that we usually carry in our pocket for under 20$

A true non contact meter requires you or an additional ground reference to provide a base line and even then the voltage displayed varies with distance from the live wire. Yes I purchased one years ago and promptly gave it away to a family member  to me it was a expensive piece of junk with a high end name.
15 years later I think I only have ever known 1 other pro to buy one, after he used it a few times it was shelved.

So your meter in NCV setting is measuring a field as it was designed to do.
Not read actual voltage

Added as requested:

To measure voltage connect the leads to the bottom 2 ports put the dial in ~V  the squiggly Line is a sine wave for AC voltage.
To measure voltage put the probes in the 2 slots of the receptacle you may need to move them to get contact and read a voltage depending on your location your reading can be from 108 to 128 volts and it’s just fine most commonly close to 120 in most of the US. Now if you want to check if the ground is connected move the probe in the longer slot to the round ground hole and the same or similar voltage if grounded or bootleg grounding hard to tell, if you measure a slight difference more likely it is a proper ground.

Comment: OK, thanks @Ed Beal, but this is disappointing obviously. Is there a way, maybe with the prods to test the voltage and determine whether or not an outlet is "live"? If so, would you mind updating your answer to give me details on how to do this? Ideally (no pun intended) I'd like to use this meter to make an accurate yea/nay decision as to whether a 3-pronged outlet (125V; 15A) or its breaker are live, and whether a NEMA 14-30 outlet and its breaker are live. Will this meter do the job safely & accurately?

Comment: Subtlety: I think EF on the display means it is will (as you say) not provide a voltage number. It doesn't mean there's an EM field detected, because EF is on the display when the meter goes in NCV mode regardless whether it's beeping/reading or not. See picture in manual, and OP's video.

Answer (score -1):

These contactless voltage tester are quite sensitive.
Besides the possibility that this tool is defect, the following points could play a role if it detects voltage everywhere in a room/house:

1. Grounding problems. F.e. multiple grounding connections instead of a star configuration with only one central connection rod. Or missing grounding of steel rebars. Or missing grounding of metal tubes in the walls, metal kitchen sinks etc.
2. A stray hot phase field which is promoted by a defect isolation and wet walls or humid air.
3. Any device in the room that could spread an electric field, f.e. in case of missing shielding in combination with no. 1 and/or 2.
4. Heavy supply lines nearby, e.g. from subway trams, electric railroads, industry buildings etc.

---

Switching all circuits off one by one (or every half per iteration step) could reveal, if and which circuit is a cause for the tester to light up at everything in a room.

Comment: This is a great theoretical textbook answer but doesn't take my question into account, nor the details of how I am using the meter. It would be a great wiki entry to stand on its own. I'm in my basement testing my sneakers. There are no "heavy supply lines" from a subway tram anywhere nearby.

Comment: A basement could be wet, and if a strong power cable with defect isolation is running along the basement, this could br the reason.
Or defect cables/devices within the basement, or a grounding problem. What happens if all circuit breakers are switched off?

Comment: Why would it beep once when I push it on my arm? Its clearly the shaking/fast movement issue pointed out in the comments above.

Comment: Hotmeatballsoup, when you rub the meter on your arm you generate a static charge, ever see a pro use one? We pull it out of our pocket , turn on if required, and rub it quickly on clothing even cotton fire resistant shirts we wear to protect from arc flash will light up a NCV tester. It is working correctly, it is a detector not a meter.